# if - while -for implemention for bison

Tags: c++, bison, interpreter, flex-lexer

I'm working on an interpreter, but I can't implement `if` , `while` , `for` on it in bison.
I wrote this code for `if` in bison:

```
if_block:
    IF '(' rule ')' '{' smt '}'
    | IF '(' rule ')' '{' smt '}' ELSE '{' smt '}'
    | IF '(' rule ')' '{' smt '}' elif_block ELSE '{' smt '}'
    ;
elif_block:
    ELIF '(' rule ')' '{' smt '}'
    | ELIF '(' rule ')' '{' smt '}' elif_block
    ;
rule:
    exp EQUAL_T exp                     { $<int_val>$ = check($<data_val>1 ,$<data_val>3); }
    ;
```

But when `rule` = 1 or `rule` = 0, `smt` runs and I got wrong answer.
Please help me, what should I do? Please give me a piece of code for `if` and `while` loop ...

Comment: "Please write my code / do homework for me" is really not what SO is about. And it is of very little value to you as a learner.

Answer (score 2):

In a loop, code needs to be executed multiple times (usually). So it cannot be executed as it is parsed, since it is only parsed once.

Similarly, in a conditional, the target(s) are executed one or zero times, but are parsed exactly once. The one which is executed zero times clearly cannot be executed as it is parsed; that would be one too many executions, as you observe.

So you have to record the result of the parse, as a syntax tree, as three address code, or in some other way, and then execute the program only after it has been fully parsed.

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: @ashkanAbd: read up on ASTs or three-address code. Check your course materials for relevant information. Talk to your TA.